# Ошибка Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Tags: c++, linux, clion

Выдает ошибку при решение задачи
входные данные
3 1
1 2
1 3
0

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    vector<vector<int>> arr;
    vector<bool> used;

    void dfs(int v) {
        used[v] = true;
        for (auto to : arr[v]) {
            if (!used[to]) {
                dfs(to);
            }
        }
    }

    int main() {
        int n, k;
        cin >> n >> k;
        int z, t;
        arr.resize(n);
        while (true) {
            cin >> z;
            if (z == 0) {
                break;
            }
            cin >> t;
            arr[z - 1].push_back(t - 1);
        }
        dfs(k - 1);
        for (auto i : used) {
            if (!i) {
                cout << "No";
                return 0;
            }
        }
        cout << "Yes";
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: *Выдает ошибку при решение задачи* - это информация, причем отрывок из обрывка, но никак не полная. А вопрос-то где? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SIGSEGV - Это ошибка по защите памяти. Т.е. ваша программв пытается обратиться к участку памяти, который ей не принадлежит. В 99% процентах случаев, такая ошибка возникает по двум причинам:

1. Индекс массива выходит за допустимый диапазон
2. Указатель получает некое "левое" (или вообще - никакого) значение.

У вас указателей нет, но есть два массива (вектора) с индексами которых далеко не всё очевидно.

Разбираться с ними глядя на код - скучно. Поэтому рекомендую скомпилировать Вашу программу с ключом -g и запустить под отладчиком gdb. Он Вам покажет конкретное место ошибки.